# Getting a module import error on fresh install

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am getting a ton of errors that are similar to the following:

[2023-09-08 16:21:46,866] [] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc [266]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util; version="[6.0.0,7.0.0)"
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2; version="[6.0.0,7.0.0)"

This is without any configurations on a fresh install.
It occurs with both OpenJDK11 and OpenJDK17

It occurs after uncompressing the zip file with the identity server blob, setting the environment variables, and executing the bin/wso2server.sh file.
I was expecting it to start without error prior to customizing the configuration, or give a configuration error.

Comment: What is the product pack (version) you are using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a fix that has been implemented by JDK [1].

According to the JDK release notes [2] [3], we can disable these newly introduced validations to preserve backward compatibility. These validations can be disabled by adding the following parameters to the wso2server.sh file located in the <WSO2_IS_HOME>/bin directory. Please stop the server and apply the parameters and start the server again.

-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true 
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \

[1] - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8251329